# Условия AND и OR в запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем!

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `$f01`='$a' OR `$f03`='$a' OR `id`>'$for_id'",$db);
```

Работает, проблем нет. Хочу кое-что добавить.

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `fieldx`='yes' AND `$f01`='$a' OR `$f03`='$a' OR `id`>'$for_id'",$db);
```

Т.е. чтобы, помимо всех условий, у всех записей строго был `fieldx`='yes'. но запрос не работает. Подскажите, в чем дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуй так:

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `fieldx`='yes' AND (`$f01`='$a' OR `$f03`='$a' OR `id`>'$for_id')",$db);
```

Comment: гениально! спасибо огромное